# Javascript button to show on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make the button visible only when there's a table shown, but it doesn't seem to be working, the button is not hiding.

PS: Sorry for not clarifying, my javascript runs onload

HTML:

```js
var DLFunc = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var DLButtons = document.getElementById("tableToCsv");
if (DLFunc == "") {
  DLButtons.style.visibility = 'hidden';
} else if (DLFunc != "") {
  DLButtons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div id="view-container">
  <main ng-view></main>
</div>
<div id="tableToCsv">
  <button class="btnCSV">CSV file</button>
</div>
```

Full HTML:

```
    <body ng-controller="DataController">
    <header ng-include="'FixedPages/header.html'"></header>
    <div ng-include="'FixedPages/mapAHH.html'"></div>
    <div id="view-container">
      <main ng-view></main>
    </div>
    <div id="tableToCsv">
    <button class="btnCSV">CSV file</button>
    </div>
    <footer ng-include="'FixedPages/footer.html'"></footer>
     <script src="js\DownloadCSV.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: i suggest get the length of element visible table then you can be sure that there is a table

Comment: Do u mind elaborating more on that? @guradio Please and thanks

Comment: something like `DLFunc.length > 0` but you have another requirement right? visible table? this will only check if there are tables you need to check if that table is visible or not

Comment: Still not working, could you help me check if my code arrangement is wrong or something? I placed the js code in DownloadCSV.js

Comment: are you running your js on load or by triggering an event?

Comment: onload by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is a table shown by counting the number of table tags. Instead of checking empty string, check for the length of the array:

```
var DLFunc = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var DLButtons = document.getElementById("tableToCsv");
if (DLFunc.length == 0) {
  DLButtons.style.visibility = 'hidden';
} else  {
  DLButtons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Also check when the code runs (maybe add an alert) as the tables may not have been created at the time your JS is running.

UPDATE:

Your JS won't pick up the table as it is run on page load, whereas AngularJS probably creates the elements later.

You can add something like the following to your DLButtons HTML:

```
<button class="btnCSV" *ngShow="hasTable()">CSV file</button>
```

Then in your Angular Component.ts/js:

```
hasTable() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName("table").length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, maybe the way i placed my code is wrong? You mind having a look for me? I updated it

Comment: Angular will add the table later, after your JS is run (it will only run once as the page loads)

Comment: It hides on default now, when i go to a page with table, it shows. But when i go to a page without table again, the button doesn't hide.

Comment: Your condition `if (DLFunc.length > 0) { DLButtons.style.visibility = 'hidden'; } else { DLButtons.style.visibility = 'visible'; }` is doing opposite of what is asked. Check my answer.

Comment: Did you just downvoted my post because I corrected you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following;

```
// you can check directly in the condition 
 const DLFunc = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
 const DLButtons = document.getElementById("tableToCsv");
 if (DLFunc)
 {
    DLButtons.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
 else 
 {
    DLButtons.style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

Comment: The button isn't showing up when I change to a view with table

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var DLFunc = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var DLButtons = document.getElementById("tableToCsv");
if (DLFunc.length == 0) {
   DLButtons.style.visibility = 'hidden';
} else {
   DLButtons.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<div id="view-container">
  <main ng-view></main>
</div>
<div id="tableToCsv">
  <button class="btnCSV">CSV file</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, maybe cause my js is loaded on page load, it's not working

Comment: @HangulSR The code is working if you add a table tag inside `<main ng-view></main>`. The rest is up to you how you place it in your markup or external JS. See sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/83L7yx5p/